# BigQuery JavaScript UDFs: Region of V8 instances

Tags: javascript, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

In BigQuery you can add JavaScript UDFs, which will be executed on an instance of V8. [This page on googleblog.com](https://developers.googleblog.com/2015/08/breaking-sql-barrier-google-bigquery.html) (just about the only page I could find on the subject) states that

> JavaScript UDFs are executed on instances of Google V8 running on Google servers. Your code runs close to your data in order to minimize added latency.

So when I have data in, for example, Europe, I expect that the UDF will be executed in the same region. However, when I run the following query it appears that the instance is not as close to my data as I expected:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION getDate()
RETURNS String
LANGUAGE js AS """
return new Date();
""";
SELECT CURRENT_DATETIME() dateTimeBigQuery
     , getDate() as dateTimeJavaScript
```

Output of this statement:

```
dateTimeBigQuery                    dateTimeJavaScript
2018-10-10T07:42:32.556699          Wed Oct 10 2018 00:42:32 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

[This page on Time functions in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/time_functions#timezone_definitions) tells me that the CURRENT_DATETIME() function returns the UTC datetime when there's no timezone specified.

[This page on Date functions in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) states

> If no arguments are provided, the constructor creates a JavaScript Date object for the current date and time according to **system settings** for timezone offset.

When I'm using data from a BigQuery table (datetime without timezone)  and passing that to the JavaScript function, it will also be return the datetime at GMT-0700

So am I safe to assume that the instance of V8 is not running close to my data?
And if that's the case, is there a way to make specify a region for that instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery overrides the constructor for `Date` to use UTC, rather than picking up the time zone from wherever the UDF is executing, in order to be consistent with the `CURRENT_DATE`, `CURRENT_DATETIME`, etc. functions. The actual V8 environments always run alongside the jobs that execute other logic in the query.

Comment: So if I understand correctly; the output of the JavaScript function is not the actual timezone of the instance it's running on here?

Comment: That's right, it's overridden to use UTC regardless of where the code is executing.